# Memory leak on classes which refer to each other

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

**For the curious**: It turns out my memory leak had nothing to do with what I put in the sample here.  I thought I had the issue nailed down to some sample code, but my sample code had different issues.  I did end up finding my *real* issue though, and that's here: [Ruby Symbol#to_proc leaks references in 1.9.2-p180?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263268/ruby-symbolto-proc-leaks-references-in-1-9-2-p180)

I have two ruby classes (`Generator` and `Member`, in this example) where Generator serves as a factory (in a loose definition of the term) of Member objects, and each Member holds a reference to the Generator that constructed it.

Code:

```
class Generator
  def new_member
    Member.new
  end
end

class Member
  attr_reader :generator

  def self.get(generator)
    @generator = generator
    puts "Provided generator: #{generator}"
    generator.new_member
  end
end
```

Using IRB, I'd expect that if I simply call I simply call `Member.get(Generator.new)`, but not actually assign the result to anything, both the reference to the newly-constructed `Generator` object and the newly-constructed `Member` object should have zero references laying around.  So the garbage collector *should* collect both objects.  But it only collects the Members, leaving the Generator sitting around:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Member.get(Generator.new)
Provided generator: #<Generator:0x007fcf398015c8>
 => #<Member:0x007fcf39801550>
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > GC.start
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > ObjectSpace.each_object(Member){|m| puts m}
 => 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > ObjectSpace.each_object(Generator){|g| puts g}
#<Generator:0x007fcf398015c8>
 => 1
```

(`ObjectSpace.each_object`, as I understand it, returns a list of references to a given class still on ruby's heap.)

Why is there still a reference to the Generator object sitting around?  I haven't saved it to a variable in any way, so there shouldn't be anything referencing it anymore.  The Member object got collected, so its instance variable that references the Generator class shouldn't be preventing it from getting collected.

I'm not just curious, either.  We have a Sinatra app that has a similar class structure, and  the equivalent Generator class stores a huge cache of Member objects, several hundred megs per request, and it never gets collected.  Ruby runs out of memory and the app server has to restart every dozen or so requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call

```
Member.get(Generator.new)
```

you set the *class instance variable* `@generator` for the Member class:

```
@generator = generator
```

And by calling the initial line Member.get(Generator.new), there is nothing that would create a Member, you simply create an instance of Generator, which is then assigned to the class instance variable.

That leaves:

- One instance of Generator assigned to Member class instance variable @generator
- No *instance* of Member was ever created
- The class instance variable @generator of Member will not get collected because the class Member will not get collected

-> The results you receive are perfectly normal, nothing wrong with Ruby's Garbage Collection.

Comment: +1 for seeing that's a *class instance* variable! Good answer! :)

Comment: You are definitely right.  And I definitely have not yet nailed down the memory leak in my application yet. :(  Turns out my application is not like my example, it doesn't set @generator in a class method like my example does, but I still see Generators sticking around in IRB without getting collected.  Fixing up my example to be more like production, and the GC picks it up just fine.  I guess I have to work more at getting a sample app that exhibits the same behavior as production.