# How thorough is GC.start in MRI Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, ruby-2.0, yarv

In MRI Ruby 2.0, how thorough is `GC.start`?

Does it try to garbage collect all objects that no longer have a reference to them? Or does it only GC objects if it thinks it's necessary?

I'm trying to track the number of objects of a certain class I have, and it seems to keep on increasing even though I think some of the objects no longer have a reference to them. Using `GC.start` doesn't fix this. I don't use any C extensions, so that can't be complicating things.

**Edit:** The problem I was having was the same as in [Ruby Symbol#to_proc leaks references in 1.9.2-p180?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263268/ruby-symbolto-proc-leaks-references-in-1-9-2-p180) - objects still existed when I thought they ought to have been garbage collected, and like in that case, the problem was to do with using implicit `Symbol` -> `Proc`. However, it would be nice to know if `GC.start` is expected to garbage collect all objects, or merely collect whatever MRI thinks is necessary to garbage collect.

Comment: It’s not clear if you’re using `GC.start` and it’s not having the effect you expect, or if you’re just seeing objects held on to longer than expected and wondering if `GC.start` will help.

Comment: Is this in a plain-old Ruby script, or in Pry/IRB? Are you looking at ObjectSpace or the process’s memory consumption?

Comment: Plain-old. BTW, I think I've got a more specific question about GC coming up.

Comment: I was getting the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263268/ruby-symbolto-proc-leaks-references-in-1-9-2-p180 . Basically, I was thinking that objects weren't getting GC'd when they should be, but it was because I was using Symbol#to_proc in the same way as that question.